# How can I convert a column of strings into hyperlink?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, hyperlink

I want to convert the column of link as a hyperlink for show it on a datatable.

The column links looks like this:

```
    link
0   https://twitter.com/CertSG/status/1286557929198563328

1   https://twitter.com/osiseguridad/status/1286565901568016384
```

I was thinking about create a function to convert de string hyperlink with `<a href = "x" </a>` where `x` is the value of `0`, `1` and else. I was also thinking that a for could help me to made it but I really don´t know what's the better way

the `type(df.link)` is `pandas.core.series.Series`
I´m using pandas 3.8.5

I want that my table looks like this in the table add links https://plotly.com/python/figure-factory-table/

Thank you very much, i´m new in this

Comment: what did you try? How about `df.apply(your_function)` ?

Comment: there is no `pandas 3.8.5` but `Python 3.8.5` and `pandas 1.1.0`

Comment: Yes, yo are right. I'm very new on this world of python so i made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.apply(convert, axis=1)` to run own function `convert()` on every row.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'link': [
        'https://twitter.com/CertSG/status/1286557929198563328',
        'https://twitter.com/osiseguridad/status/1286565901568016384'
    ]
})

def convert(row):
    #print(row)
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(row['link'],  row.name)

df['link'] = df.apply(convert, axis=1)

print(df)

# Display it with `plotly`

import plotly.figure_factory as ff

fig = ff.create_table(df)
fig.show()
```

---

**EDIT:** Display directly in `streamlit`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'link': [
        'https://twitter.com/CertSG/status/1286557929198563328',
        'https://twitter.com/osiseguridad/status/1286565901568016384'
    ]
})

def convert(row):
    #print(row)
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(row['link'],  row.name)

df['link'] = df.apply(convert, axis=1)

print(df)

import streamlit as st

st.write(df.to_html(escape=False), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Comment: Hi furas!
Thanks for your answer, I really liked the way you do this, because i was thinking about doing someting like that but i want that the output be a Hyperlink and that way still returns me a string

Comment: in `pandas` it will be always string. It can be Hyperlink only when you display it with tool which display it in web browser and it can treat it as Hyperlink.

Comment: I added `plotly.figure_factory` in code and it shows me web page with hyperlinks.

Comment: I´m displaying it on streamlit and it doesn´t works :c

Comment: you didn't mentioned `streamlit` in question but you shown `plotly`. How do you display it ? Do you generate HTML and send to template? If it works like Flask then it may need option `safe` to treat it as HTML - `{{ html | safe }}`

Comment: Hi furas, you are right. It works! 
I´m very glad for your answer
Thank you 
Can I ask you other thing? 
How can i change the name of the row? i want that instead of 0,1,2, (....) appears "display"

Comment: On streamlit the graphs of plotly appears the same that you have, cause streamlit have an extension that shows plotly charts

Comment: this works for me `st.write(df.to_html(escape=False), unsafe_allow_html=True)`. If you want to change text in link then use it in `'<a href="{}">display</a>'`

Comment: in wich part? on the fuction ?

Comment: do you ask for `st.write()` ? See new code in answer. Do you ask for `'<a href="{}">display</a>'` ? You have it in function `convert()`

Comment: I´m asking for the  '<a href="{}">display</a> because it still appear the number of the row

Comment: did you use it instead of `<a href="{}">{}</a>` in `convert()`? Maybe you would have to show it on image because `plotly` and `st.write()` give me different table - first shows me only column `link` with text `display`. `st.write()` shows me column `link` with `display` and indexes with numbers which you can remove `df.to_html(escape=False, index=False)`

Comment: It is perfect!
Thank you very much, you help me a lot. 
I´m new at this page, it exist a part to recommend you or something like that?

Comment: I don't know page about pandas. I learn on Stackoverflow - I search question and see answers and later I try to resolve similar problems in other questions. Using Googl I found [awesome-pandas](https://github.com/tommyod/awesome-pandas)

Comment: on pandas page is link to free PDF [pandas: powerful Python data analysistoolkit](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.1/pandas.pdf)